# Getting Clip raster ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, clip, error-1

I want to clip a raster using a polygon I made. However, I get the following error message.

[image]

I've tried all the possible options but somehow I'm not being able to clip it.

QGIS 2.16.2 on Windows 10

Comment: Don't forget to save the edits to your shapefile before you clip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that you didn't define the path of the output raster image. It is just written "myClip".

Also, make sure that both clipping (cutline) polygon and raster image have the same projection. If cutline and raster data have different projections, it will not produce the desired output of cropping the image to the extent of the polygon.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error message although the projections were the same. In my case the error came because I tried to do the clipping with a layer that was still in editing mode, i.e. the clipping polygon was not saved to disk yet. After ending editing mode and saving the layer to disk it worked.

Comment: You saved my brain.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too, got the same error. In my case the problem was that I tried clipping while the mask shape layer was still in edit mode and the layer edits were not saved (even though the mask layer appeared correctly in the "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" parameters window). Once I saved the layer edits and exited edit mode, mask clipping was successful with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error while trying to run the clip algorithm as a batch process.

In my case, the problem was that my vector (mask) layer was a memory (virtual/temporary) layer. I exported the layer and saved permanently to disk and the algorithm went well.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in the attribute table. I opened the attribute table and there were three features. After deleting two, it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved.

ahmadhanb was correct. I needed to make sure the polygon and the raster image were in the same projection. Right clicking each layer and modifying the projection took care of it.

Many thanks.