QGIS v.3.34.8 Prisren: ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features. Process returned error code 1
Like others, I am having a problem clipping a raster with a polygon. I downloaded a georeferenced JPEG from NearMap at the highest resolution (0.149 m/pixel).  I started a new project and added the raster which set the CRS of the project.  I created a New Temporary Scratch Layer which adopts the CRS of the project. I created a polygon then used Raster>Extraction>Clip Raster by Mask Layer. It resulted in this message: ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features.
Process returned error code 1.
I converted the JPEG to a GeoTIFF with the CRS of the project and repeated the clip.  Same results.
I created a geopackage polygon and repeated the clip on the GeoTIFF.  Same results.
I repeated the clip with the geopackage polygon on the JPEG.  Same results.
Examining the properties, I confirmed that the CSR is consistent across all two layers in the project.
I ran the same processes above starting a new blank project each time.  Same results.
I have run out of tests to identify the problem. Can anyone suggest a solution to fix such a simple process?
I was able to use the mask based clipping a couple of days ago on the same data and it worked fine.

Works for me without issues with QGIS 3.41 and Natural Earth raster file "HYP_50M_SR_W.tif" and a temporary scratch layer just a you described. If it worked for you couple of days ago it feels like something has changed in your system since that. I think I would create a new user profile first, and if it does not help, reinstall QGIS.

Did you save and stop editing the vector layer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/210427/2856

Your title has a different error to the question body.
